# Determine number of crossing points in Lissajous trajectory on sphere surface.

Tags: analytic-geometry, surfaces

Is there a possibility to analytically determine how often a [Lissajous curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) on the surface of a sphere crosses itself?

The Lissajous figure (on the unit sphere) is given by:

x = $ \sin(n_{\theta} t) \cos(n_{\phi} t) $

y = $ \sin(n_{\theta} t) \sin(n_{\phi} t) $

z = $  \cos(n_{\theta} t) $

where $n_{\theta}$ and $n_{\phi}$ are arbitrary integers and $t \in [0, 2\pi)$.

An example for such a trajectory on a sphere with $n_{\phi}=21$ and $n_{\theta}=20$ is given in this image: [image: Lissajous trajectory]

Comment: Why the ‘linear algebra’ tag?

Comment: Maybe "Analytic geometry" would be more accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer [this arxiv.org article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.06546.pdf). The number of crossing points is:

$ n_{\theta}  ~( n_{\phi} -1) +2 $

The two poles of the sphere are traversersed $ n_{\theta}$ times while $t$ runs from $0$ to $\pi$. The remaining points are travesed two times each.

Answer (score 0):

The poles are obviously two crossing points.  If you want to consider each pair of arcs separately, there are obviously $n_\theta(n_\theta+1)$ polar crossings.

Having made some sketches, I think there are simply $n_\theta n_\phi$ non-polar crossings, for a total of $n_\theta (n_\phi + n_\theta + 1)$.

Comment: I think your formula is not correct. Consider the case n_theta = n_phi. In that case the trajectory has exactly ONE crossing point.

Comment: Oops, change +1 to -1 throughout.